# Matlab Simulation(Statistics)

Tags: matlab, math, statistics, histogram

I want to simulate 150,000 random values of Y^x and create a histogram of them. Can anyone show me how to do this on matlab?

Comment: How are you getting `Y` and `x`? What distribution, or generative process, or whatever?

Comment: sorry x and y are uniform distributions. U=Y^x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Y = y_lower + (y_upper-y_lower) * rand(150000,1);
x = x_lower + (x_upper-x_lower) * rand(150000,1);

U = Y .^ x;
hist(U);
```

Example output for `Y` from 5 to 8 and `x` from 2 to 2.5:
[image]

Comment: Is it still ok if i do it without y_lower/upper and x_upper/lower..for ex: y=randn(150000,1)

Comment: @Speed Of course, but that'd give you samples from the standard normal distribution instead of a uniform. `rand` gives you uniform(0, 1); `randn` gives you normal(0, 1).

Comment: You should vote up and accept this very good answer.  Your thanks, while appreciated, aren't as good as doing the right thing.  It's good for you and the folks answering your questions.

Comment: @duffymo Speed does not have the reputation required to accept an answer (unless StackOverflow has changed this somewhat recently).
I believe the magic reputation required is 15. Speed only has 1.